# Question about probability of order statistics

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm given two exponential random variables $x_1$, $x_2$ that both have a mean of $1$ (so $\lambda = 1$ for both r.v.s, presumably), and asked to solve for the probability:
$$P(X_{(2)} \gt 3*X_{(1)})$$

Not sure about how to approach this. I think I've solved for the joint distribution of the order statistics correctly ($f_{x_{(1)},x_{(2)}}(x_1,x_2)=2e^{-x_1}*e^{-x_2}$ when $0 \lt x_1\lt x_2$), but don't know where to go for there.

Thanks for y'alls help, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The joint density function is correct. For the required probability, draw a picture, calling the usual $x$-axis the $x_1$-axis, and the usual $y$-axis the $x_2$-axis. Find
$$\iint_A 2e^{-x_1}e^{-x_2}\,dx_1\,dx_2,$$
where $A$ is the part of the first quadrant that is above the line $x_2=3x_1$. This can be expressed as the iterated integral
$$\int_{0}^\infty \left(\int_{3x_1}^\infty  2e^{-x_1}e^{-x_2}\,dx_2\right)\,dx_1.$$

**Remark:** In this case, we do not need the joint density function of the order statistics. Let our two exponential random variables be $X$ and $Y$. With probability $\frac{1}{2}$, we have $X\lt Y$, and with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ we have $Y\lt X$. Thus the required probability is
$$\frac{1}{2}\Pr(Y\gt 3X)+\frac{1}{2}\Pr(X\gt 3Y).$$
Each probability is computed by finding a double integral very much in the style of the above answer.

Comment: The picture gets me every time! Thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome. I cannot have confidence that what I am doing is right without drawing a picture.

Comment: Quick question: are the bounds for the outer integral $x_1$ to infinity, or 0 to infinity? Just want to be sure -- thanks!

Comment: Zero to infinity. Thanks for spotting it!

Comment: And since $X$ and $Y$ are iid, both $P\{Y > 3X\}$ and $P\{X > 3Y\}$ have the same value and so only one double integral need be evaluated.